# Android Studio APK install error: "local path doesn't exist"

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, gradle, android-studio

I get the following output when hitting the "run" or "debug" button in Android Studio:

> Waiting for device. Target device: emulator-5554 (2.2) Uploading file
>     local path:
>   /Users/myname/Development/TestProject/Test/build/apk/Test-debug-unaligned.apk
>     remote path: /data/local/tmp/nz.co.adbc.testproject Installing
>   nz.co.adbc.testproject DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r
>   "/data/local/tmp/nz.co.adbc.testproject" pkg:
>   /data/local/tmp/nz.co.adbc.testproject Success
>
> Uploading file    local path:
>   /Users/myname/Development/TestProjectProject/actionbarsherlock/build/libs/actionbarsherlock-debug.aar
>     remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.actionbarsherlock
>   **Local path doesn't exist.**

Because of this error (in bold), it doesn't start the intent. Therefore I can't debug my app in Android Studio.

The app works fine otherwise. It still installs and runs fine (when launched manually from the app drawer).

Has anyone seen this error before and have any info on why it is trying to upload the aar file of actionbarsherlock? Shouldn't it just upload my apk which would include the aar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. My project was depending on both the aar and the project itself.

File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Your Project -> Dependencies -> Uncheck the project (only depend on the aar)

Comment: I unchecked the project and relaunched Android Stuido. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Only exit the Android Studio and relaunch it... In my case, I am using both the module project and its library ".aar" as dependencies

Answer (score 6):

The best way to fix your problem with it.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4WcMIyc8OQ

Good Luck =D

Comment: Surprisingly this suggestion works!  Though I'd have to say that if you have sensitive ears, fast forward to about 90 seconds, after the video author has finished cussing out Android / Android Studio ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it's because I originally used Build Tools 17. I later updated my Build Tools to 19 and deleted the old Build Tools. That caused the "Local Path Doesn't Exist".

Answer (score 1):

follow these steps. This worked for me...

- Go to your project directory.In that directory search for .apk file....
- You will find a apk with name of your project+debug-unalighned.apk.
- Open .iml file insideyour project folder that contain project source directory.
- Open and add write `<option name="APK_PATH" value="/build/apk/(apk file name that was found earlier with apk extension)" />` inside `<configration> <configration/>` tags.
- Now go and run your project...

PROBLEM SOLVED.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix - go to File -> Project Structure and look for the Project Compiler Output heading (on Project, the defualt screen) - make sure that path exists (add folders if necessary), seems like Studio can't/won't do it automatically

worked for me anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Build -> Clean Project

Step 2:
Tools -> Android -> Sync Project With Gradle Files