# Old Android project refusing to build. "Local path doesn't exist"

Tags: android, android-studio

I've loaded up one of my old Android projects in Android Studio (originally built in this IDE, and the IDE itself hasn't been updated since), but I can't seem to run it. I instead receive the following output:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: 015d483b8963fc02
Uploading file
    local path: /....../build/classes/debug/.......apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/......
Local path doesn't exist.
```

(Truncated the paths as they're long and unimportant).

I've been tinkering with other projects recently and they all run fine, but this particular one is refusing to play regardless of which device I plug in as a testbed. The other projects are all PhoneGap while this one is native Java, if that offers any clues.

I've tried the Build->Rebuild Project to no avail, and I've checked the manifest etc for common errors. Other people have reported success running Tools->Android->Sync Project with Gradle Files which for me has resulted in the following error:

```
Can't deserialize target data of key 'IdeaAndroidProject'. Given class loaders:[PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.0]]
```

Any thoughts please?

UPDATE:

I just updated from Android Studio 0.2 to 0.4, then ran Build -> Clean Project, Build -> Rebuild Project, Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Attempting to run came up with the same original error, but this time I was given the additional error of my Gradle build being too old (or the build referenced by the project at least). I hit a link to automatically fix this, by repointing to Gradle 1.9, and now I'm getting the error "Gradle version 1.6 is required. Current version is 1.9".

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869611/android-studio-apk-install-error-local-path-doesnt-exist?rq=1

Comment: Hi TGMCians,
 
I did look over that thread, yes. My Project Structure->Modules tab doesn't seem to have any odd looking dependencies, but it does show two variants of the project (one with spaces, the other in CamelCase). I figured a rebuild/sync would resolve that if it's an error?
 
The Project Compiler Output setting looks fine to me too. I have the full directory path, but not the actual file that the compiler was meant to create.

Comment: Just switched from IcedTea JDK to Sun JDK, and still getting the same errors after another Gradle Sync and a Rebuild Project.

Comment: Post your build.gradle, your settings.gradle, and gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: Hi @GabrieleMariotti,
 
build.gradle = http://pastebin.com/pTAy95sc
 
settings.gradle is just a single include line
 
gradle-wrapper.properties = http://pastebin.com/GpJ4CdXV

Comment: Change classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+' in  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'  and compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+' in compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'  (or.19, check which version you installed in your SDK)

Answer (score 0):

Aha, fixed!

I updated all the API's etc. through the SDK manager, then amended build.gradle to load 0.7.+ in as a classpath instead of 0.5.+, and now all is happy again.

Not sure why the Gradle sync didn't know to update this value though.

Cheers.